# Change order of columns in tab "Products" of category

Tags: category, admin, grid, column

I would like to change the order of columns in tab "Products" of the categories, "SKU" should be after "ID".
I have put a local.xml in app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/local.xml containing the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <adminhtml_catalog_category_tab_product>
        <reference name="category.grid">
            <action method="addColumnsOrder">
                <columnId>sku</columnId>
                <after>entity_id</after>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_catalog_category_tab_product>
</layout>
```

It works, but when I click on the SKU to sort then the SKU jumps back to its orignal place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Need to rewrite the Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Product block to achieve this.for this create a small module.follow my steps

Step 1 : Create Module's xml file at `app/etc/modules/Mylife_Adminhtml` with following content.Here Mylife is my packagename you can have anything and Adminhtml is my module name

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mylife_Adminhtml>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Mylife_Adminhtml>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Step 2: Create `Mylife/Adminhtml/etc` at `app/code/local` and create `config.xml` file with the following content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mylife_Adminhtml>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Mylife_Adminhtml>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <catalog_category_tab_product>Mylife_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Product</catalog_category_tab_product>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Step 3: Create `Mylife/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tab/Product.php` with the following content

```
<?php
    class Mylife_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Product extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Product
    {
        protected function _prepareColumns()
        {
            $this->addColumnAfter('sku', array(
                'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('SKU'),
                'width'     => '80',
                'index'     => 'sku'
            ),'entity_id');

            parent::_prepareColumns();
        }
    }
?>
```

Note: Here, **SKU** column will be shown just after **Id #** column. If you put **parent::_prepareColumns();** after **$this->addColumnAfter**.If you put **parent::_prepareColumns();** before **$this->addColumnAfter** then it will not display just after **ID #** column.

Comment: Now it's works! Great work

Answer (score 0):

> It works, but when I click on the SKU to sort then the SKU jumps back to its orignal place.

That's because sorting and filtering happens with an AJAX request to a different route, `adminhtml_catalog_category_grid`. So please try (additionally to what you already got):

```
<adminhtml_catalog_category_grid>
    <reference name="category.grid">
        <action method="addColumnsOrder">
            <columnId>sku</columnId>
            <after>entity_id</after>
        </action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_catalog_category_grid>
```

You can also remove duplication with a named handle:

```
<change_category_column_order>
    <reference name="category.grid">
        <action method="addColumnsOrder">
            <columnId>sku</columnId>
            <after>entity_id</after>
        </action>
    </reference>
</change_category_column_order>
<adminhtml_catalog_category_tab_product>
    <update handle="change_category_column_order" />
</adminhtml_catalog_category_tab_product>
<adminhtml_catalog_category_grid>
    <update handle="change_category_column_order" />
</adminhtml_catalog_category_grid>
```